# numpy submatrix 3D using a single indexing item

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indexing

I have a 3D numpy array:

```
K = (np.arange(36)).reshape((4,3,3))+1
[[[ 1  2  3]
[ 4  5  6]
[ 7  8  9]]

[[10 11 12]
[13 14 15]
[16 17 18]]

[[19 20 21]
[22 23 24]
[25 26 27]]

[[28 29 30]
[31 32 33]
[34 35 36]]]
```

where each item in K is a matrix.
Now, I want to get all 2D submatrix using a certain index vector

I know that it is possible in this way:

```
idx = np.s_[:,:2,:2]
K_sub = K[idx]
[[[ 1  2]
[ 4  5]]

[[10 11]
[13 14]]

[[19 20]
[22 23]]

[[28 29]
[31 32]]]
```

The problem is that I want to use an arbitrary indexing array and not slicing to select rows and cols.

Moreover, I want to use a single object to get the list of submatrices, something like:

```
K_sub = [magic_indexing]
```

and not:

```
K_sub = np.array([k_[train][:,train] for k_ in K])
```

Exists a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's simply enough for you, but one way would be with [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) and thus uses [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), like so -

```
K[np.ix_(np.arange(K.shape[0]), train, train)]
```